# Upper triangular determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given that
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&211&311&327&337\\
0&2&427&438&491\\
0&0&3&547&551\\
0&0&0&2&672\\
0&0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Find $|2A^{-1}+I_5|$. The solution is $\frac{100}{3}$ but I can't figure out how to do it. Any hints? My best guess is to use properties of the determinants of upper triangular matrices, but then I got lost in the algebra...

Comment: $2A^{-1}+I_5$ is upper triangular. The off diagonal terms of $A$ are irrelevant.

Comment: Eigenvalues of triangular matrices are on the diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one comment notes, the fact that the $A^{-1}$ is upper triangular should be sufficient to figure things out.

Alternatively, here's an approach that doesn't require this knowledge or a familiarity with the idea of eigenvalues; it only requires that you know how to find the determinant of an upper triangular matrix. We have
$$
|2A^{-1} + I| = |(2I + A)A^{-1}| = |2I + A| \cdot |A^{-1}| = \frac{|2I + A|}{|A|}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix are precisely the entries of the main diagonal.
2. If $A$ is invertible then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$
3. Eigenvalues are polynomial invariant i.e $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ implies $p(\lambda) $ is an eigenvalue of $p(A) $ where $p(x) \in K[x]$
4. $\det A$ is the product of all eigenvalues taking care of multiplicity.

---

> Eigenvalues of $A$ are $1, 2,3,2,3$.

> Hence eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2},  \frac{1}{3}$

> Now eigenvalues of $2A^{-1}+I_5$ are $2\cdot 1+1, 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1, 2\cdot \frac{1}{3}+1, 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1, 2\cdot\frac{1}{3}+1$

> $\begin{align}&|2A^{-1}+I_5|\\&=3\cdot 2\cdot \frac{5}{3}\cdot 2\cdot \frac{5}{3}\\&=\frac{100}{3}\end{align}$